# how to insert boolean expression as values to the Datagridcell of a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have created a **Matrix** kind `Datagrid` using the following XAML in my application.

**XAML**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Matrix_datagrid">           
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock 
             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
             Path=Item.Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Availability"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CPU"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RAM"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hard Disk"/>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                    
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>          
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server2"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server3"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server4"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server5"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Output**

[image: Matrix Output]

I want to evaluate a Boolean expression in the datagridcell.
for each X and corresponding Y axis , I have boolean expression to be evaluated.

for example I have a list of expression to the Servers is to its functionalities like this,

(row,column)

```
(0,0)  - Expression is ((True && False) || (True && True)) 

(0,1)  - Expression is ((True && True) && (True || false))
```

and so on..

how to insert these expression into the datagridcells? kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it by triggers, the simplest way, is to define a custom dataTemplate for the Datagrid's cells, and in that datatemplate define your triggers.

This way the triggers will be applied for all the cells of your grid, without having to browse through them.

Comment: I meant Triggers is for the red/green color animation. but my question is for how can I access the datagrid cells, so that I can use my boolean expression in the corresponding X and Y row/column